# jquery and jquery mobile files are conflicting

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get the height of a div, below is my code

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loginH = $(".loginStyle").height();
    alert(loginH);
});
</script>
```

Here it is alerting 0 as it's height, but the div's height is 300px. When I remove the line of including jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js, it is working well.

I have tried $.noConflict() also without success.

Any ideas??

Comment: Is it possible that the height of the div is 0 because it first has to be toggled some way to appear (assuming it's a login-screen)

Comment: Instead of document.ready use one of the jQM events like pagecreate or the pagecontainer widget's show: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show  Probably jQM has not yet enhanced the page when document.read() runs.